# set_xticks is causing the data in my graphs to get squashed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to graph data of different frequencies some of my data is 55H while the other dataset I have is 4Hz.

So far I have all the values graphed on the same timescale, I am now just trying to set my xticks, I have had no problem with the yticks, however when I try to set the xticks it causes graph to squash up see the image.

The code below is the function I used to graph the dataset, which produced the graph below this. As you can see the green line, my gaze targets have been squashed if I comment out

*host.set_xticks(xlables)*

I get the graph I want but without the correct ticks.

Can't really figure out what's up, and to be honest, the code is pretty messy, as I have struggled to graph data of different lengths.

Help much appreciated

```py
import sys
import csv
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
from math import isclose
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
from functools import reduce
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plticker

# Function for location detection 

# You will need to merge data what ever sensor you are using with the GPS data on timestamp
# Pass your GPS start and end lat and lon and the merged dataframe to the function
def GPS_find_loc(gps_startLat, gps_startLon, gps_endLat, gps_endLon, df): 
    locList = []
    #dfnew = df[['latatude', 'longatude']].copy()
    #dfnew = dfnew.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if isclose(row['latitude'], gps_startLat, abs_tol=1e-4) == True and isclose(row['longitude'], gps_startLon, abs_tol=1e-4) == True:
            locList.append(index)

        elif isclose(row['latitude'], gps_endLat, abs_tol=1e-4) == True and isclose(row['longitude'], gps_endLon, abs_tol=1e-4) == True:
            locList.append(index)
    Start = locList[0]
    End = locList[-1]
    return Start, End

def plotGaze(Loc, lat, lon, Par, location):

    time = df.timestamp[lon] - df.timestamp[lat]


    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,7.5))
    host = fig.add_subplot(111)

    par1 = host.twinx()
    par2 = host.twinx()
    par3 = host.twinx()

    host.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
    host.set_ylabel("Gaze targets")
    par1.set_ylabel("Pressure on Acc (bar)")
    par2.set_ylabel("Pressure (bar)")
    par3.set_ylabel("HR")

    color1 = "g"
    color2 = "b"
    color3 = "y"
    color4 = "r"

    x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, len(df.objectName[lat:lon].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)))
    x3 = np.linspace(0, 1, len(df.HR[lat:lon].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)))

    mean = np.mean(df.HR.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))


    p1, = host.plot(x1, df.objectName[lat:lon].dropna().reset_index(drop=True), label='Object', color='g', linewidth=0.5)

    p2, = par1.plot(x1, df.pressureOnAccPeddle[lat:lon].dropna().reset_index(drop=True).rolling(13).median(), label='Acc pedel', color='b', linewidth=0.5)

    p3, = par2.plot(x1, df.pressure[lat:lon].dropna().reset_index(drop=True).rolling(13).median(), label='Acc pedel', color='y', linewidth=0.5)
# df.HR is at a lower frequency 
    p4, = par3.plot(x3, df.HR[lat:lon].dropna().reset_index(drop=True), label='Acc pedel', color='r', linewidth=0.5)

    par3.axhline(y=mean, label='Mean= ' + format(round(mean, 1)), color='r', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)

    lns = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

# Setting outer spines
    par2.spines['right'].set_position(('outward', 90))  
    par3.spines['right'].set_position(('outward', 40))     


    xlables = np.arange(0, time)

    host.set_xticks(xlables)

    host.set_xticklabels(xlables, fontsize='small')



    labels = [item.get_text() for item in host.get_yticklabels()]
    labels = ('IVI','Cluster','RearViewMirror','Others','RightSideViewMirror','Right_Others','Windshield','FrontalArea','Left_Others','LeftSideViewMirror')

    host.set_yticklabels(labels, color=color1,fontsize='small')

    #host.set_yticklabels(np.arange(8),('IVI','Cluster','RearViewMirror','Others','RightSideViewMirror','Right_Others','Windshield','FrontalArea','Left_Others','LeftSideViewMirror'))


    #host_subplot.yticks(np.arange(10),('IVI','Cluster','RearViewMirror','Others','RightSideViewMirror','Right_Others','Windshield','FrontalArea','Left_Others','LeftSideViewMirror'))
    host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    par1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
    par2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())
    par3.yaxis.label.set_color(p4.get_color())

    fig.tight_layout() 

file_name_HR = "stackoverflowexample.csv"
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.6f' % x)
df =  pd.read_csv(file_name_HR, sep=',', header=0) 

LatStartBrown, LonStartBrown =  53.279644, -9.069730
bExitlat, bExitlon = 53.278779, -9.069806
BrownStart, BrownEnd = GPS_find_loc(LatStartBrown, LonStartBrown, bExitlat, bExitlon, df)
df[BrownStart:BrownEnd].to_csv("C:/PhD Tests/Results/stackoverflowexample.csv") 
plotGaze("_Brown.png", BrownStart, BrownEnd, Par, "Brown")
```

My reputation isn't high enough to post the image but you can take a look below

Please find the data below
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zdayM5JWLLYLA_bokaWw8EVLzDRFlQ21

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUSY6.png

Comment: What is `time`? How does it look. Can you provide the complete dataset so that we can run your code?

Comment: Time calculated from a timestamp in the dataset, lat and lon are the index values of the time period I am graphing. Provide the dataset due to data protection, I could maybe set an example up on GitHub?

Comment: Can you try `xlables = np.arange(0, len(time))` and then `host.set_xticks(xlables)`?

Comment: Can't do that because time is a 'numpy.float64'

Comment: Ok, try `xlables = np.arange(0, len(x1))`?

Comment: I tried that but I changed it to `xlables = np.arange(0, len(x1)/54)` as that gives me the correct time rather than the number of samples. I am still getting the squashing of the graph though

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get more concrete answers and help

Comment: Just to be clear, the ticks are correct, and if I do it without the ticks the data is correct, but when I do both together I get the squashing effect

Comment: @Sheldore All should be there now

Comment: You need to put your times in the same units when you plot.  You don’t do this by kicking with the tick labels you do this by doing plot(time4hz, signal4hz) and plot(time55hz, signal55hz)

Comment: @JodyKlymak not sure if this is possible though, the 4Hz signal won't populate the whole graph this way. I might have misunderstood what you mean though

Comment: Strongly recommend you strip out all the twinx stuff and plot this on three or four separate subplots, get your limits and labels sorted out and then go back to the twinx.  This is far from minimal, and its very hard to tell where you have gone wrong